# Pyspark function read error - NameError: name 'spark' is not defined

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use the below code

```
import pyspark 
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
df = spark.read.format('db').load()
```

but get an error below:

> NameError: name 'spark' is not defined

Have already tried with [pyspark : NameError: name 'spark' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541204/pyspark-nameerror-name-spark-is-not-defined) and [NameError: name 'spark' is not defined, how to solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61690673/nameerror-name-spark-is-not-defined-how-to-solve) and using which I get another error related to Java Gateway

> PySparkRuntimeError: [JAVA_GATEWAY_EXITED] Java gateway process exited before sending its port number.

I'm using Windows

Please help with how to solve this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyspark: Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841509/pyspark-exception-java-gateway-process-exited-before-sending-the-driver-its-po)

Comment: Can you help with understanding the solution @samkart, because the link shared has no accepted answer and I didn't quite get the solution if any, thanks

Comment: the issue can be due to multiple reasons. you could start by checking Java installation and it's path being correctly referred in your spark configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first create a SparkSession. Following is an example-

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('NameOfYourApp').getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.format('db').load()
```

If this doesn't work, then it has something to do with environment variables. Check if JAVA_HOME, SPARK_HOME environment variables are set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, you have to first open a spark session:

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
```

For the second question, you have to make sure that your java is correctly installed and JAVA_HOME is correctly set.